# Rails - set a default picture for user from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am pretty new to rails and i  want to set profile image of the user if he didnt provide one and to save it to database 
user controller create action

```
  def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
@user.profilePicture
if(@user.profilePicture.length==0)
  profilePicture="/assets/images/default_image.jpg" # problem is here
end
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  end
end
```

end

schema of user

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "fisrt_name"
t.string   "email"
t.string   "password"
t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
t.string   "profilePicture"
```

end

thanks in advance :)

Comment: change `profilePicture="/assets/images/default_image.jpg"` to `@user.profilePicture="/assets/images/default_image.jpg"`

Comment: same problem, forgot to put @user while  removing fail attempts

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 2):

This will set the new value only if the old value is blank

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
@user.profilePicture ||= "/assets/images/default_image.jpg"
```

If `profilePicture` could be an empty string then we might treat it like this

```
@user.profilePicture = "/assets/images/default_image.jpg" if @user.profilePicture.empty?
```

Comment: if it didn't work then `profilePicture` already had a value, check that

Comment: i am sure it is empty, i put an wrong code that generate error (just for the sake of debugging) under the if condition( that check if it is empty) and rails only detect this error if i didnt insert an image

Comment: If it's an empty string but not nil then use the second part I added to the answer.

Comment: Can't you just see what the  value is rather than try and deduce it from error codes etc?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady raise an error "undefined method `empty?' for #<ImageUploader:0x562b018>"
@MaxWilliams i am printing it but i am doing this for being sure i am not very good in using controllers so it is the easiest way to me although it is the ugliest

Comment: ok now that's the issue, image is of type `image_uploader`, is that a gem or something?